# How could django's save() method of model know where to save among db tables?

Tags: django, django-models

Save() function must know where to save data, especially the exact table.
Assume that there exist Question model and I create a new record and save it through q.save() like below.
Although I haven't give the information of table actually, but it works well.
I want to know how save() method can know the table name needed.

```
def create_question(request, question):
    q = Question(question_text=question, pub_date=timezone.now())pub_date=timezone.now())
    q.save()
```

Comment: You have made a connection to a specific `db` and a model which by default looks to the `public` schema. I believe you have a table `Question` in that schema instantiated in your `Models` as a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It obtains this out of the `_meta` of the `Question` model. Indeed, you can obtain the name of the table with:

```
Question._meta.db_table
```

So if your application is named `app`, then likely the name is:

```
>>> Question._meta.db_table
'app_question'
```

Note that you can specify the name of the table yourself, by specifying a [**`db_table`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table) to the `Meta` of the model. For example:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'name_of_question_table'
```